# Stream camera video with ffmpeg in Firefox via dash.js

Tags: firefox, ffmpeg, streaming, hls, mpeg-dash

I am trying to stream live video from a camera using ffmpeg to a browser. I have found several questions about this on StackOverflow and here, but they all pertain to creating a video file from a camera. Fortunately, I am able to make a video file from my camera input without too much issue. But I need help making a video stream from the camera, ideally as a .mpd file for a browser to play.

## Issue

Chromium-based browsers play the streaming audio and video, but Firefox only plays the audio and does not show video.

## Background

An excellent Udemy tutorial provided me this command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920":audio="Microphone (HD Pro Webcam C920)" -rtbufsize 256M -hls_master_name stream.m3u8 -hls_playlist 1 -seg_duration 2 stream.mpd
```

Notice I am working on Windows right now, but I'm hoping things will work the same on Linux, my ultimate target.

I have tried different cameras with the same result, so I don't think the camera itself matters.

This command creates the .mpd file and various chunk files as I would expect. I'm using the [dashjs player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dashjs) to play the streaming video. In summary, the code looks like this:

### JS

```javascript
import dashjs from 'dashjs'
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
const thevideo = ref(null)
onMounted(() => {
  const player = dashjs.MediaPlayer().create();
               player.initialize(thevideo.value!, '/stream/stream.m3u8', true);
}
```

### HTML

```html
<video width=600 height=300 ref="thevideo" controls></video>
```

I am using Vue right now, but you can set this up anyway you'd like, as I'm just trying to test this.

As I mentioned, this setup works great in browsers like Chrome and Edge. I use `ffmpeg` to create the `stream.mpd` directly in the `public` folder and the dash.js player is able to play the video and audio.

However, this same page in Firefox results in only the audio loading. I am not finding errors that appear to pertain to the video downloading or being processed by the browser. It just won't load video.

Might anyone know what's going on here?

By the way, when I try a command like this to make an HLS stream:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HD Pro Webcam C920":audio="Microphone (HD Pro Webcam C920)" -rtbufsize 265M -fflags flush_packets -max_delay 5 -flags -global_header -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 3 -y stream.m3u8
```

no browser is able to play the .m3u8 file. I see no errors in Chrome, but Firefox is saying it cannot parse stream.m3u8 as an XML file. I don't know why it's trying to because it's not an XML file and I never said to treat it as such. **However**, when I use this command with an actual video file as input instead of camera input, it works well.

I'm okay just working with mpeg-dash, but if someone could help me make a m3u8 from camera input, I'd appreciate that as well. But at the very least I would love help making the MPEG-DASH stream work in Firefox. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried playing the .m3u8 with ffplay? That might help to further isolate the issue.  Also, according to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1263150 firefox does not support mpeg dash

Comment: I just now used ffplay to play the stream files and it does so no problem. ffplay can play both the stream.mpd and stream.m3u8 created from the same first command.

Comment: Also, I cannot get dash.js to play the m3u8 file from my camera nor from an MP4 file. I am also trying [Shaka player](https://developers.google.com/widevine/open-source/shaka-player) and it is able to play either m3u8 or mpd from a camera input or MP4 file only in Chrome, not in Firefox. I am holding out for Firefox and .mpd because of [this demo](https://reference.dashif.org/dash.js/latest/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html)

Comment: Sorry, correction for my previous comment. dash.js might not be meant for m3u8, because the error keeps saying malformed XML and m3u8 is not XML, but mpd is. I should clarify that I am seeing Shaka player play either m3u8 or mpd in Chrome and Firefox when I use an MP4 file as input. With camera input, only Shaka in Chrome plays the m3u8 and mpd, whereas Shaka is not playing them in Firefox. The closest I get with .mpd from camera input and Firefox is dash.js, but it only plays the audio and shows now video...

Comment: Is there an alternative format to .mpd that would work?

Comment: I don't mind using something else. My main goal is to stream video from a camera into the browser, but I would hope any browser, even if I must use one of these players. I did look into live streaming servers, but I was hoping to keep this more compact. There must be a way ffmpeg can provide the video data in a manner Firefox is okay with, not to mention any other browser. I feel like I am so close but one little thing is missing.

Comment: @Abnormal I think I finally found the problem. Thanks for investigating!

Comment: awesome! nice fix

Answer (score 1):

I finally found [this issue in Shaka player](https://github.com/shaka-project/shaka-player/issues/2910), and it is talking about my exact problem. Now I swear I already tried adding `-vf format=yuv420p`, but I did it one more time and now the video is showing up in Firefox. I'm not clear on all the details, but it's something about how Firefox expects a more common kind of "[colorspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling)" for this video.